# Are there differences between "/\((.*)\)/" and "/\(([^\)]*)\)/"?

Tags: javascript, regex

Are there differences between `/\((.*)\)/` and `/\(([^\)]*)\)/`?
In particular, would the second regular expression match a line ending, while the first one would not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, AFAIK the dot does not match newlines in most regex engines without a modifier.

EDIT: Apparently JS doesn't even have that option. I personally think negated character classes are the way to go; I barely use the dot in regex.

Comment: `[\s\S]` is the most common idiom for "anything including a newline" in JavaScript.  And +1 for avoiding the dot; it's a good way to improve your regex-fu, by forcing yourself to think about what the regex engine is doing.

Answer (score 2):

Another important difference is that the dot *will* match `)`.  Suppose you're you're trying to match the first parenthetical expression in

```
blah blah (foo) blah blah (bar)
```

The regex `/\(.*\)/` will match `(foo) blah blah (bar)` because the `*` is greedy.  You can fix that by using a reluctant quantifier instead - `/\(.*?\)/` - but what if you want to match the *last* one?  You know it's the last thing in the string, so you just add the end-of-string anchor - `/\(.*?\)$/` - but now it's back to matching `(foo) blah blah (bar)` again.  Only the negated character class will give you what you want in this case: `/\([^)]*\)$/`.